# Regular expression to match numbers between 1-5000

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to use a regex for a textbox that allows only numbers between 1-5000

I've tried the following but it wont work:

```
@"/^(?:1|5000|-[1-9]\d?)$/
```

Comment: Why not just parse the string and see if its in range?..

Comment: @ThomasAyoub Or [_Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 
“I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems._](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247) ;)

Comment: 1|5000 will literally match 1 *or* 5000, *not* anything in the range 1 - 5000.

Comment: If you have determined that a regex is *required*, can you give us the context in which it is used?

Comment: No need asking at SO if there are such well-known services as [this one](http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/) or [this](https://www.richie-bendall.ml/ros-regex-numeric-range-generator/), or [this one](https://www.myregextester.com/index.php), also see [how to do that programmatically](https://github.com/voronind/range-regex) in Python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `^(?:[1-9]|\d{2,3}|[1-4]\d{3}|5000)$`. But you'd better to parse to Int then do simple maths.

Comment: Why make it a non-capturing group?  Does that improve performance?

Comment: @juharr it's an old habit from complicated regex: *capture only what you **need** to capture*. For the performances, I **think** that it's the same thing.

Comment: This will match both 0 and the empty string

Comment: Doesn't match 500-999 now

Comment: it match even if the numbers are preceded by zeroes... like 09, 009, 099...

Comment: @GianniB. Is 09 != 9?

Comment: the `string` is different

Comment: @GianniB. OP's talking about integers, not string.

Comment: I'm not sure that something like "09" is a problem *per se*. However, it'll match things like "00" and "0000," which is out of range; other than those "edge cases" I think that this is correct. It will *not* match "0" itself.

Answer (score 5):

With some parsing beforehand, you can make the regex very simple:

```
string s = textBox1.Text;
string r = "";
int n = 0;
if (int.TryParse(s, out n) && (n>=1 && n<=5000))
{
    r = "y";
}

if (Regex.IsMatch(r, "y")) {
    // input was valid
    MessageBox.Show("OK");
}
```

Comment: Yes, I think it would be simpler to just do something like that (try to parse it as an int to make sure it *is* an integer and then test it to see if it's in range) and avoid the regex.

Comment: Cheers for trolling RegEx.

Comment: Regex could even be `Regex.IsMatch(r, ".")` ;)

Comment: I love this one pretty much, but cannot upvote this. No way, sorry:)

Answer (score 3):

Try ...

^(?:[1-4][0-9]{1,3}|[1-9][0-9]{0,2}|5000)$

Comment: Looking at this I think this is the correct answer, I came up with something similar but his was first to the correct answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like the following:

```
^(([1-4][0-9]{0,3})|([1-9][0-9]{0,2})|(5000))$
```

The first two groups will match anything in the range of 1 - 4999. You add the |5000 at the end to make it match the range 1 - 5000. The three cases here are:

- The number is exactly 5000
- The number is between 1 and 3 digits. In this case, it can't possibly be more than 5000. However, the first number must be 1 - 9 so that you can't get something like "009" or "000."
- The number is 4 digits, in which case it must be between 1000 - 4999

With that said, I think it would probably be simpler to just parse the int and see if it's in range.

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this (0-366)

```
 ^(0?[0-9]?[0-9]|[1-2][0-9][0-9]|3[0-5][0-9]|36[0-6])$
```

Comment: Best to give an answer for the specific question instead of a specific answer for a similar question.

Comment: How does this answers the question?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub I was wondering the same thing, I voted to close this for not being an answer.

Comment: Let me re-read the question for ya: 

"I would like to use a regex for a textbox that allows only numbers between 1-5000" 

This is an example that "allows" numbers from 0-366.

Comment: Would you consider an answer that gave a Regex for range 0-1 a good answer for this question?

Comment: No. You point is?

Look. We don't write college text books here. We don't have to post a solution for the exact problem.
It doesn't even have to work. We point people in the right direction. We help.

Also it's not fair to downvote the question because our instict tells us that it may 
not be a good idea to do it. There's no such thing as bad question.