# RegEx Expression /w limited length and chars

Tags: regex

My question is NOT similiar to [Regular expression to match numbers between 1-5000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39473119/regular-expression-to-match-numbers-between-1-5000), because I have something else to check (no range, leading and no leading zeroes, etc.).

I have the following RegEx in an input check:

```
^[0-9]{1,4}$
```

This works for digits with 1-4 length.

Unfortunately I have to allow only these combinations:

- One digit numbers 1-9 (no leading zeroes)
- or two digits numbers 10-30 (no leading zeroes)
- or four digits numbers 0001-9999 (with leading zeroes).

What RegEx do I need?

Comment: You need the or operator, `|`. Something like `^([0-9]{1,4}|foo|bar)$`, where foo is two digits numbers 10-30 (no leading zeroes), and bar is four digits numbers 0001-9999 (with leading zeroes). If you could write the regex you've got, you can write those -- the `|` operator is all you're missing.

Comment: Try [`^([1-9][0-9]?|[0-9]{4})$`](https://regex101.com/r/BVC4YE/3). I guess you need to skip the numbers from `100` to `999` altogether, right? And does `10-30` range is just an example, and you want the 2-digit numbers from `10` to `99` or really only up to `30` only?

Comment: Then try [`^([1-9]|[12][0-9]|30|[0-9]{4})$`](https://regex101.com/r/BVC4YE/4)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match numbers between 1-5000](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39473119/regular-expression-to-match-numbers-between-1-5000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define subpatterns for your conditions:

> *One digit numbers 1-9 (no leading zeroes)* - **Use `[1-9]`**
>   *or two digits numbers 10-30 (no leading zeroes)* - **Use `[12][0-9]|30`**
>   *or four digits numbers 0001-9999 (with leading zeroes)* - **Use `[0-9]{4}`**

So, the whole pattern should be built from those alternatives that should be anchored and grouped (so that the anchors were applied to the group)

```
^([1-9]|[12][0-9]|30|[0-9]{4})$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BVC4YE/4)

Comment: As I can see, this perecisely solves my problem. Thank you!